# Do the badge requirements make sense given the size of the community?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, badges

Obviously gamedev will continue to grow; stackoverflow wasn't built in a day, for instance.

But it does seem fairly obvious that there are a *heck* of a lot more "developers" out there than there are "game developers". And so it seems pretty absurd when you look at some of the requirements for badges on gamedev, and how in many instances, no-one (or *very* few people) have managed to earn them in the 2(?) years this site's been online.

These may make sense for stackoverflow, where there are nigh on 600k users and 2 million questions, and it's thus pretty easy to, for example, "edit 500 crappy posts". But not so much here, where there are about 8k users and 4k questions.

I expect I'll get a lot of flak for this, but before you say anything, I only ever play hardcore mode :) So I'll understand if some people think "making things easier" would suck.

I guess also it may not be doable at this stage, considering that would make devalue what others have earned up till now. But perhaps something to consider for future sites coming out of Area51.

Comment: http://stackexchange.com/sites#gamedev "created 1 year, 1 month ago"

Comment: @Jeff ah thank you -- my mistake! But presumably it was in beta for at least 3 months before that?

Comment: no, that is the date from inception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd also like to see it - but [don't hold your breath](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96408/is-it-possible-to-adjust-the-requirements-for-badges-in-an-se-site-according-to-t). :)

> For better or for worse, badges mean the same thing in the nooks and
>   crannies of SO and on the smaller SE sites as they do in highly
>   popular central core of SO. Arguments can be made for certain special
>   cases, but I don't think scaling all badges by size of user base would
>   be an effective way to even things out.

Also see [Shouldn't the badge requirements scale?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69689/shouldnt-the-badge-requirements-scale)